# Count lower case characters in a string

Tags: python

What is the most pythonic and/or efficient way to count the number of characters in a string that are lowercase?

Here's the first thing that came to mind:

```
def n_lower_chars(string):
    return sum([int(c.islower()) for c in string])
```

Comment: You should use generator comprehension `sum(int(c.islower()) for c in string)`

Comment: And you don't need the `int` part. This would work: `sum(c.islower() for c in string)`

Comment: No need to convert to int. True and False are equal to 1 and 0, and True+True=2.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Clever trick of yours! However, I find it more readable to filter the lower chars, adding 1 for each one.

```
def n_lower_chars(string):
    return sum(1 for c in string if c.islower())
```

Also, we do not need to create a new list for that, so removing the `[]` will make `sum()` work over an iterator, which consumes less memory.

Comment: +1 for version that works for bytestrings, Unicode strings, Python 2, Python 3 in a memory efficient manner.

Answer (score 9):

```
def n_lower_chars(string):
    return len(filter(str.islower, string))
```

Comment: +1. `filter()` on Python 2 returns a string if input is a string so it won't eat more than twice the memory and it should be faster than `sum()` over a generator in most cases. Though `len(filter())` breaks on Python 3 where it returns an iterator.

Answer (score 6):

```
def n_lower_chars(string):
    return sum(map(str.islower, string))
```

Comment: You can cut the computation time in half by replacing your lambda expression with `str.islower`

Comment: Only now do I know that `In [39]: sum([True, True, False, False, True]) Out[39]: 3` after running it in shell.

Comment: @JoelCornett nice suggestion - putting it in above :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to divide things a little more finely:

```
from collections import Counter

text = "ABC abc 123"
print Counter("lower" if c.islower() else 
              "upper" if c.isupper() else
              "neither" for c in text)
```